# difference between Target Action and Key Value Observer in iOS

Tags: ios, design-patterns

What is the difference between the two? To me both look like doing the same thing i.e notify an event observer about some event.

I read this post http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns regarding the actual pattern in use for the two above mentioned event handling techniques but failed to understand how command pattern is different from observer pattern or am I missing something.

Answer (score 4):

In target-action, the object controlling the event is told what to trigger from that event. The most common use of this for iOS developers is not NSInvocation, but Interface Builder. The sender is usually a UIControl.

In NSNotification, a notification is broadcast to whoever is listening for a particular event. These notifications are pretty generic, and can contain any information. The listeners may or may not care who the sender is.

In KVO, the listeners pay attention to specific properties of a particular object.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of them is the next:
In the case of target action, you have the Notification Center through which you pass your info between two classes. You have one class which sends out the notification to the Notification Center which will broadcast the info and the second class which has the observers will listen for any broadcast that matches its criteria.

While in the case of KVO you have an object which is capable of observing the change of one of it's properties. 
So no one is posting any notification in the case of KVO. Hope this cleared things up at least a bit.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply... I m a little bit confused as to how it differs from the observer pattern as the post i mentioned mentions it to be command pattern but still i see that the underlying event handling mechanism is similar to the observer pattern... raise an event when something occurs(e.x. change of value or say a tap event being raised in an uiview ) and send it to the observees... what actually is the differentiating factor between the two ?

Comment: In the case of KVO, the observer is the class you are working with (so there is no external observer), and it observes one of its own properties. The Notification Center is not involved in this procces, so there is no info broadcasting.

Comment: Target-action has nothing to do with Notification Center.

Comment: when should i prefer using target-action over KVO or vice versa?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet you should see notifications as a one to many type of situation. Ex: you post the notification from one place and listen for it in multiple places, while KVO should be used only for checking if a property of an object changed. Another thing is that Apple seems to be moving slowly away from KVO, so maybe you should avoid it all together. You can use delegation, notifications or Combine to pass data around.

Comment: right now I'm heavily making use of delegation to pass data around, but I'm wondering if notifications are more convenient because the prior iOS app developer was using it quite a bit more. I've basically made an app by myself in about 3 months (around 80-85% done), but I still haven't used notifications. So I'm wondering whether I should be using it more.  Too much work, not enough experience.